# sum up float/decimal numbers from textarea with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text area with float/decimal number in it. I want to get that value and sum it up but apparently, the code I found on the internet ignored "," and "."

How can I make it work with decimal/float numbers ?

```js
var text1 = $('#lp').html();
var a = text1.match(/\d+/g);

var text2 = $('#tl').html();
var b = text2.match(/\d+/g);


var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  sum += parseFloat(a[i]);
}
var sum2 = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  sum2 += parseFloat(b[i]);
}
console.log(sum + sum2); //this shows 76


var sum1 = 0;
var numbers1 = $("#lp").text().match(/\d+/g);

if (numbers1) {
  $.each(numbers1, function() {
    sum1 += parseFloat(this);
  });
}
console.log(sum1)

var sum2 = 0;
var numbers2 = $("#tl").text().match(/\d+/g);

if (numbers2) {
  $.each(numbers2, function() {
    sum2 += parseFloat(this);
  });
}
console.log(sum2) //this code fail to show the 2nd alert box
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="lp" name="luas_program" rows="6" cols="20">
             4
             2            this shows 16
             2
             8
            </textarea>

<textarea id="tl" name="total_luas" rows="6" cols="20">
               4.463
            1.35
            0.9               this shows 515
            0.3             
            </textarea> <br>
```

Comment: Please look in the console for errors. You had a typo. The answer to your real question is posted below

Comment: *«the code I found on the internet»* doesn't work as I wish...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you're using `\d+` works for only integers. What it means is "give me all the digits". What you need instead is "give me all digits with floating point too".

For that, the regex would be:

```
/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/
```